# Maven Surefire plugin is not picking the parameters

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, testng-eclipse

Maven Surefire plugin is not picking the parameters. When I run the Regression Suite xml in eclipse it works fine. But the same xml does not work when I run as Maven test.For some reason it is not picking up the parameters. I have been struggling with this for a while. Please help. Thanks

RegressionSuite.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name= "RegressionTests">
  <suite-files>
    <!-- suite-file path="CreateUsers.xml"-->
    <suite-file path="ReportFormatting.xml" />
    <suite-file path="SectionsFormating.xml" />
    <suite-file path="ColumnFormatting.xml" />
    <suite-file path="AdvancedFunctions.xml" />
    <suite-file path="AnalysisStyle.xml" />
    <suite-file path="CalculatedFields.xml" />
    <suite-file path="Aggregration.xml" />
    <!-- suite-file path="Admin.xml"/-->
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Here is my POM

```html
plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>8</source>
<target>8</target>
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe</executable>
</configuration>
</plugin>
 
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.21.0</version>
 <executions>
<execution>
<id>test</id>
<phase>integration-test</phase>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>
 <suiteXmlFile>
          src\test\resources\RegressionTests.xml
 </suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
  <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
      </execution>
      
      </executions>
     </plugin>


</plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the error message

```
enParameter 'userName' is required by @Test on method Date_Aggregration but has not been marked @Optional or defined

    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParams(Parameters.java:290)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParametersForMethod(Parameters.java:359)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:620)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:769)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)ter code here
```

Here is my ReportFormatting.xml

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression - Report Formatting" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">


<listeners>
<listener class-name="y.bi.extentReportListener.ExtentReportListener"/>
</listeners>



 <parameter name="axisA" value="1" />
 <parameter name="axisB" value="2" />
 <parameter name="viewName" value="Ski Team"></parameter>

 <!-- REPORT FIELDS -->
 <!-- this is your report data set -->
 <parameter name="rf1" value="Athlete Country" />
 <parameter name="rf2" value="Agency Country" />
 <parameter name="rf3" value="Invoiced Amount" />
 <parameter name="rf4" value="Athlete Counter" />
 <parameter name="rf5" value="Invoice Estimate" />
 
 <!-- Data Section font type and size fields -->
 <parameter name="fontType" value="Courier"></parameter>
 <parameter name="fontSize" value="16"></parameter>
 
 <!-- Column and Row Header font type and size  -->
 <parameter name="headerFontType" value="Helvetica"></parameter>
 <parameter name="headerFontSize" value="18"></parameter>
 
 <!-- Border Width  -->
 <parameter name="borderWidth" value="Thick"></parameter>
 
 <!-- Title and Description  -->
 <parameter name="displayTitleFontType" value="Roboto"></parameter>
 <parameter name="displayTitleFontSize" value="20"></parameter>
 <parameter name="displayDescFontType" value="Geneva"></parameter>
 <parameter name="displayDescFontSize" value="19"></parameter>
 
 <!-- yellowfin login credentials -->
 <parameter name="URL" value="http://10.10.5.77:8082/" />
 <parameter name="userName" value="admin" />
 <parameter name="passsword" value="test" />
>
 
 <test name="ReportFormatting">
  <classes>
   <class name="y.bi.test.ReportFormatting">
    <methods>

     <include name="ValidateDataSection"></include>
     <include name="ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder"></include>
     <include name="ValidateTitleandDescription"></include>
     <include name="ValidateHeaderFooterandTableSort"></include>
     <!-- <include name=""></include> -->

    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You have used username parameter in your testcase, but I can't see any username you have passed. The error itself is telling you that if it is required parameter then pass it from a configuration file or make it an Optional parameter

Comment: @AmitBhoraniya please do not simply downgrade the question. I have researched hard to find the solution. Since I could not I have raised it in stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: Facing exact same problem but no accepted answers around SO are solving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your pom file.
You have bound the surefire-plugin to the `integration-test` phase and within `surefire-plugin` you have configured it to work with the suite xml file.

But by default the super pom of all pom files also has a `surefire-plugin` that is defined to execute at the `test` phase. `test` phase comes before `integration-test` phase.

So Maven is basically going to run `surefire-plugin` twice : Once for `test` phase and once for `integration-test` phase.

Now since the `test` phase bound `surefire-plugin` is being executed without any suite file bound to it, I guess its finding `@Test` methods which are annotated with `@Parameters` annotation for which values are not being passed (remember that here no suite xml file is involved here), resulting in the error.

To fix the problem please update the phase value of your `surefire-plugin` and

- **Change:** `<phase>integration-test</phase>`
- **To:** `<phase>test</phase>` (or you can remove the `<phase>` entry itself, which will cause Maven to fall back to defaults)